# What is the order of ActiveRecord callbacks and validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I was wondering in what order are callbacks and validations called when an ActiveRecord object is created.

Let’s say I have some custom validations & callbacks like the following:

```
validates :reference_code, :if => :reference_code, :on => :create
before_create :assign_reference
```

which one will run first? The callback needs to happen first or else the validation may fail.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The most-up-to-date version of this list for the latest version of Rails can be found in the [`ActiveRecord::Callbacks` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). The lists for Rails 4, 3 & 2 are below.

### Rails 4

The most up-to-date version of this list can be found in the [Rails 4 Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks).

#### Creating an object

- `before_validation`
- `after_validation`
- `before_save`
- `around_save`
- `before_create`
- `around_create`
- `after_create`
- `after_save`
- `after_commit/after_rollback`

#### Updating an object

- `before_validation`
- `after_validation`
- `before_save`
- `around_save`
- `before_update`
- `around_update`
- `after_update`
- `after_save`
- `after_commit/after_rollback`

#### Destroying an object

- `before_destroy`
- `around_destroy`
- `after_destroy`
- `after_commit/after_rollback`

### Rails 3

The most up-to-date version of this list can be found in the [Rails 3 Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks).

#### Creating an object

- `before_validation`
- `after_validation`
- `before_save`
- `around_save`
- `before_create`
- `around_create`
- `after_create`
- `after_save`

#### Updating an object

- `before_validation`
- `after_validation`
- `before_save`
- `around_save`
- `before_update`
- `around_update`
- `after_update`
- `after_save`

#### Destroying an object

- `before_destroy`
- `around_destroy`
- `after_destroy`

### Rails 2

The most up-to-date version of this list can be found in the [Rails 2.3 Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks)

#### Creating an object

- `before_validation`
- `before_validation_on_create`
- `after_validation`
- `after_validation_on_create`
- `before_save`
- `before_create`
- *`INSERT`* operation
- `after_create`
- `after_save`

#### Updating an object

- `before_validation`
- `before_validation_on_update`
- `after_validation`
- `after_validation_on_update`
- `before_save`
- `before_update`
- *`UPDATE`* operation
- `after_update`
- `after_save`

#### Destroying an object

- `before_destroy`
- *`DELETE` operation*
- `after_destroy`

Since you need to first validate the `reference_code`, the `assign_reference` method can be called in the `after_validation` callback or any callback appearing after it in the list I provided above.

Comment: what about before/after_initialize?

Answer (score 6):

## Rails 5

Here is a [list with all the available Active Record callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks), listed in the same order in which they will get called during the respective operations:

### 1 Creating an Object

- `before_validation`
- `after_validation`
- `before_save`
- `around_save`
- `before_create`
- `around_create`
- `after_create`
- `after_save`
- `after_commit/after_rollback`

## 2 Updating an Object

- `before_validation`
- `after_validation`
- `before_save`
- `around_save`
- `before_update`
- `around_update`
- `after_update`
- `after_save`
- `after_commit/after_rollback`

### 3 Destroying an Object

- `before_destroy`
- `around_destroy`
- `after_destroy`
- `after_commit/after_rollback`

`after_save` runs both on create and update, but always after the more specific callbacks `after_create` and `after_update`, no matter the order in which the macro calls were executed.

`before_destroy` callbacks should be placed before `dependent: :destroy` associations (or use the prepend: true option), to ensure they execute before the records are deleted by `dependent: :destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to knowing the order in which each type of callback is called relative to the others, it's also important to be aware of the execution order of multiple callbacks of the same type. `before_*` hooks are executed in the order in which you define them, but `after_*` hooks are executed in *reverse* order. This can be surprising if you don't know it.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Ordering+callbacks

Comment: This is a bit misleading. Only in the case of multiple **transactional** callbacks is the order reversed. This means callbacks like `after_commit` and `after_rollback` _but not_ `after_save`, `after_update`, `after_create`, etc.

From your link: _"...in case there are multiple transactional callbacks the order is reversed."_