# Rails: Validation Being Called After before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, callback

As far as I can tell, [validations are suppose to run before callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks). I'm getting behavior that suggests otherwise, though. Specifically, I have:

```
class User::GroupInvitation < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :user_can_be_invited

  before_create :find_or_create_membership

  private

    def user_can_be_invited
      user_membership = User::Membership.where(:group_id => self.group_id, :user_id => self.invitee_id).first
      if user_membership.present?
        case user_membership.status
        when "invited"
          errors[:base] << I18n.t("user.group_invitations.create.this_user_is_already_invited")
        end
      end
    end

    def find_or_create_membership
      user_membership = User::Membership.where(:group_id => self.group_id, :user_id => self.invitee_id).first_or_create(:status => "invited")
      user_membership.update_column(:status, "invited") unless user_membership.new_record?
      self.user_membership_id = user_membership.id
    end
end
```

Testing this code, I consistently get the error "This user is already invited," even when the user hasn't been previously invited. My best guess is that this is happening because `find_or_create_membership` is running first, thereby setting `status` to `invited`. Any ideas about what's going on or how to resolve the situation?

Answer (score 11):

`find_or_create_membership` is running first

The order of the actions while creating:

```
before_validation
after_validation
before_save
around_save
before_create
after_create
after_save
```

Comment: Is there any way to have it run afterwards? I tried changing `after_create` to `after_validation`, but I got the same behavior.

Comment: I don't understand your code clearly, but to reverse the order of your callbacks, you can call the `user_can_be_invited` on the `after_create` or `after_save` callback. Work around it, i posted up the order of callbacks.

Comment: Can you see this pdf?
https://www.edx.org/static/content-berkeley-cs169.2x~2013_Spring/handouts/slides/169.2x-Wk1-LS1.pdf

The order is from the page 2 of that pdf.

Comment: also check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969673/what-is-the-order-of-activerecord-callbacks-and-validations

Comment: Looking at page 2, it appears that validations do actually run before a `before_create` callback, which is odd considering how my code is behaving.

Comment: Just removed `user_can_be_invited` from the validations and placed it in the `before_create` queue just before `find_or_create_membership`. This remedies the bug I was experiencing before, but perhaps only because `user_can_be_invited` is no longer running properly. Even when a user is invited, I don't get the appropriate error message.

Answer (score 2):

The problem actually stems from my controller:

```
invitation = User::GroupInvitation.create(params[:user_group_invitation])
if invitation.valid?
  . . . .
else
  . . . .
end
```

This caused the validation method to get called a second time during `invitation.valid?`, and of course it would send the error message then as a `status` had already been set. Fixing the problem was easy. I simply added an `:on => :create` condition:

```
validate :user_can_be_invited, :on => :create
```