# Rails Validations on Non-User chosen fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, token

Is it necessary to create validations in the model for a field that the user does not affect?

By necessary I mean is a best-practice.

I have a before_create filter that sets a user token to a user account. Should I add validations even though I'm (the backend code) the only thing that has power over this field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do. It allows me to keep data integrity in my database.

Comment: Pretty much this. Also what happens when somebody else uses your code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the order of Active record callbacks,

The most-up-to-date version of this list for the latest version of Rails can be found in the http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html. The lists for Rails 3 & 2 are below.

### Rails 3

The most up-to-date version of this list can be found in the [Rails 3 guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks).

#### Creating an object

- `before_validation`
- `after_validation`
- `before_save`
- `around_save`
- `before_create`
- `around_create`
- `after_create`
- `after_save`

**In this case as you are setting the value after the validation, the validation error will trigger everytime**

Source - [What is the order of ActiveRecord callbacks and validations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969673/what-is-the-order-of-activerecord-callbacks-and-validations)

Comment: Not entirely sure if this answer is helping.