# Display error from before_save callback in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rails-admin

I am trying to create a callback for an object that can be created in the `rails_admin`. Im my model I have the following before_save callback.

```
def check_remaining
  if c.purchased_a == 0
    errors.add(:base, "Some error message here")
  end
end
```

I am trying to get the error message displayed in the rails_admin if the condition in the callback is true when a user goes to create said object. After they hit save I expect the error message to be shown but instead the object actually gets created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `before_save` to validate your model before save. You should use `validate` instead. Try something like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :c  # As you mark somewhere.
  validate :check_remaining

  def check_remaining
    errors.add(:base, "Some error message here") if c.purchased_a == 0
  end
end
```

**Explanation**

[validate](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validate) is used to add custom validations to your model. This happens even if the model isn't saved. You can check model errors every time you want with `model.errors`.

`before_save` callback [happens after](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11021211/4084391) model validation. So, do validations there, will not work at all because they won't be evaluated. `before_save` is used when you want to set an attribute, or calculate some value, and stuffs like that.

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

Since C is another model that this object belongs to you change the if statement to:

`if self.c.purchased_a  == 0`

Comment: c comes from a belongs_to

Comment: Then try self.c.purchased_a==0

Comment: doesn't change anything. the callback get's run but i need the error to show up in the rails-admin page

Comment: If you show me your controller that is passing this to the model I can show you what to do to have it displayed in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Standard method of catching errors in Model:

As, stated here [ActiveModel::Errors < Object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html)

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Required dependency for ActiveModel::Errors
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  def initialize
    @errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
  end

  attr_accessor :purchased_a
  attr_reader   :errors

  def validate!
    errors.add(:purchased_a, "Some error message here") if c.purchased_a == 0
  end

end
```

The above allows you to do:

```
Foo = Foo.new
Foo.validate!            # => ["Some error message here"]
Foo.errors.full_messages # => ["purchased_a Some error message here"]
```

I'm not sure what or where is the source of **c** in **c.purchased_a**.
Please modify the code for it.